# Zippy Chirp - 100% CPU

Tags: visual-studio, minify, chirpy

I installed [Chirpy](http://chirpy.codeplex.com/) under VS 2010 SP1, created a small all.chirp.config and saved it.

The Output windows displays the line:

> ConfigEngine -- C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyPrj\Website\Content\all.chirp.config

over and over and over, while my CPU gets pegged...

The config file contains:

```
<root>
  <FileGroup Name="system.css">
    <File Path="Fonts/all.css" />
    <File Path="Google.Prettify.css" />
  </FileGroup>

  <FileGroup Name="MyPrj.css">
    <File Path="site.css" />
    <Folder Path="MyPrj" Pattern="*.css" />
  </FileGroup>

  <FileGroup Name="system.js">
    <File Path="../Scripts/browserDetect.js" />
  </FileGroup>
  <FileGroup Name="MyPrj.js">
    <Folder Path="../Scripts/MyPrj" Pattern="*.js" />
  </FileGroup>
</root>
```

where the first folder (with the *.css) contains 6 files and the second (with the *.js) contains 14 files. should be no big deal...

Note: I get the error: `The 'root' element is not declared` from the tool

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? As far as I can tell, its due to the `Folder` element. If I get rid of that and change it to be hardcoded Files it works.. but I would rather use the folder element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out. The path attribute is not valid on a `folder` element. You need to change the `Folder` to be:

```
<Folder Pattern="../Scripts/MyPrj/*.js" />
```

Otherwise your just telling chirpy to process all js files in your root directory and end up get stuck in an infinite loop trying to minify your output.

Also just a FYI I found the folder node supports the `Deep` attribute. Setting this to false, ensures it does not look in any subdirectories.

Comment: cool.  thanks for posting the answer.  I gave up on it and went to Cassette.

Comment: Interesting.. I havent looked into Cassette yet, but I've been looking for a replacement to Chirpy as i've been finding it's not yet ready for prime time.